# How to show tabs At Bottom rather then at top?

Tags: android

I m having following screen,
[image]

I am using Following code to make Layout to show tabhost and tab widget

[image]

I want to place the tabs at bottom .
Please tell how to do this.

Comment: Why do you post your code as an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I've done this using following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its not working with android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.
plz suggest

Answer (score 1):

Try this it comes below..In tab widget you have to specify the gravity of appereance of the Tab (i.e,) v

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#000000" android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:background="@drawable/gradient_black"
        android:gravity="bottom" android:listSelector="#999999"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="63dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code shows Tabs at the bottom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs">
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```