# android tabwidget need help

Tags: android, tabwidget

Hello all this is my code for the tab layout in to android i want them in to bottom of the scrren currently it shows me at top of the screen

***main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <HorizontalScrollView android:scrollbars="none"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

***tab.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_background_selector" android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/tab_icon" android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tab_text" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="10sp" android:padding="3dip" android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my activity class
***TestActivity.java***

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class TestActivity extends TabActivity {
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maiin);  
         final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) getTabHost();
            tabHost.addTab(createTab(MobiintheMorningActivity.class, 
                    "Welcome", "Welcome", R.drawable.icon));      

            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width = 85;
            }

        private TabSpec createTab(final Class<?> intentClass, final String tag, 
                final String title, final int drawable)
        {
            final Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, intentClass);

            final View tab = LayoutInflater.from(getTabHost().getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.tab, null);
            ((TextView)tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_text)).setText(title);
            ((ImageView)tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon)).setImageResource(drawable);

            return getTabHost().newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tab).setContent(intent);
        }
    }
```

here i've used `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` but no effects at all what should i do? what thing i am missing? thanks in advance :Pragna

Comment: -1 The poster obviously did not search for a similar question before asking this one. Poster defined an almost useless title for the question (title should have been "How to show tabs At Bottom rather then at top?", which happens to be the title of the solution given by Muhammad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402328/how-to-show-tabs-at-bottom-rather-then-at-top) to put the tab bar at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of FrameLayout and widget in your xml.I think that my help you